# HTML DOM (js if don't work on first click on element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I'm writing a page in a school and i wrote a js code because i wanted to show span on click and hide it on another click, so i did was:

```
function gbcn(name) {
return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
}
var txt = gbcn('txt');
function display(variable, number) {
  if(variable[number].style.display == 'none') variable[number].style.display = 'block';
  else variable[number].style.display = 'none';
}
```

I have an object with class 'txt' and in external css file i gave him display: none; property, but this code in js don't see (i think) this external property and give property of display: none; in html.

[When i click an element to show me .txt object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apWXn.jpg)

[2nd click (not third xd) and it shows me the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72dCx.jpg)

Why it don't see display: none; property in external css file?

I got one more problem:

i have div with id content and he have box-shadow property, i wrote a code in js to change it when i click on a  tag in navigation: (What i tried to do is delete the box shadow property of the container box on the right with iframe inside when i click on the link in menu to open page in iframe imgur.com/a/41pdI)

```
var n = document.getElementById("content");

function hdd() {
    n.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px black';
}
```

but it sends an error Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at hdd, when i changed it from id to class it worked but it crashed a bit.

```js
function gbcn(name) {
 return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
}

var n = document.getElementById("content");
var txt = gbcn('txt');

function display(variable, number) {
  var s = variable[number].style;
  s.display = s.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

function hdd() {
 n.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px black';
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: antiquewhite;
 font-family: Arial;
}

#bd {
 
}

#content-wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
}

#heading {
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%); /*linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);*/
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#w {
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
}

#m {
 position: relative;
 top: -60px;
 left: 10px;
}

#j {
 position: relative;
 top: -225px;
 left: 80px;
}

#cmsimg {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

#cms {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 130px;
 padding-top: 25px;
 float: left;
 width: 800px;
 height: 175px;
 letter-spacing: 50px;
 text-shadow: 10px 10px 4px gray;
 color: #263275;
}

nav {
 float: left;
 width: 230px;
 height: 760px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 50px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

iframe {
 width: 750px;
 height: 760px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#content {
 width: 750px;
 height: 760px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

footer {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

.li1 {
 list-style-image: url("grafika/ww.png");
}

.li2 {
 list-style-image: url("grafika/jj.png");
}

.li3 {
 list-style-image: url("grafika/mm.png"); 
}

ul {
 -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white
}

a:hover {
 color: antiquewhite;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}
/*OTHER SITES*/
#wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 width: 700px;
 min-height: 600px;
 background: linear-gradient(141deg, #1fc9be 30%, #2fd9ec 80%, #3dc6f9 90%);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#nagłówek {
 width: 700px;
 /*background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0d968a 0%, #0da6b9 51%, #0a93c6 75%);*/
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#nazwa {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 130px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 450px;
 height: 190px;
 text-shadow: 10px 10px 4px gray;
 color: #263275;
}

#img {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

#obraz {
 left: 25px;
 top: 25px;
 position: relative;
}

#treść {
 width: 700px;
 min-height: 530px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 /*background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0d968a 0%, #0da6b9 51%, #0a93c6 75%);*/
    color: white;
    opacity:0.95;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.button {
 width: 700px;
 height: 50px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black, 0px 0px 20px black;
 background: linear-gradient(141deg, #1fc9be 30%, #2fd9ec 80%, #3dc6f9 90%);
}

.txt {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 680px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #0d978b;
 border-top: 10px solid #0d978b;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
 display: none;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="heading">
   <div id="cmsimg">
    <img src="grafika/w.png" width="130px" height="130px" id="w">
    <img src="grafika/m.png" width="130px" height="130px" id="m">
    <img src="grafika/j.png" width="130px" height="130px" id="j">
   </div>
   <div id="cms">
    CMS
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <a onclick="hdd()" href="wordpress.html" target="iframe"><li class="li1">Wordpress</li></a>
    <a href="joomla.html" target="iframe"><li class="li2">Joomla!</li></a>
    <a href="moodle.html" target="iframe"><li class="li3">Moodle</li></a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
   <iframe name="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <footer>99081105119</footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your html too so we can see the current behavior?

Comment: to post your html, While creating or editing a post press "Ctrl+M" to switch to the code editor. it will help other users to help you better.

Comment: can i add somehow external pages included in my page to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display.style` will be `""` initially if you set `display` in a stylesheet. Therefore `if(variable[number].style.display == 'none')` will fail even though the element isn't visible.

Checking the current `style.display` is a bad idea in general; you should use a variable to store the state, switch the variable, then set the style based on the variable.

For a quick and dirty fix, switch the logic around:

```
function display(variable, number) {
  var s = variable[number].style;
  s.display = s.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

(However this will only work for elements starting out as `display: none`, otherwise the first function call will fail for the same reason as your version.)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the DOMElement.style object is the same as the style-attribute.

If you apply something with an external stylesheet, you need the [Computed Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must writing some code:

```
    ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    max-width: 200px;
}

ul.menu > li {
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;

    padding: 5px 0;

    border-radius: 10px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #dedede;
}

ul.menu > li > div.info {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu > li > div.info.active {
    display: block;

    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="btn">
    One

    <div class="info">One a ponce a time</div>
</li>
<li class="btn">
    Two
    <div class="info">Two moons</div>
</li>
<li class="btn">
    Three
    <div class="info">Three pigs</div>
</li>
```

JS:

```
 (function() {
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

    Object.keys(btns).map(function(key) {
        var btn = btns[key];

        btn.onclick = function (event) {
            var info = event.target.getElementsByClassName('info');

            if (info.length) {
                if (info[0].className.indexOf('active') < 0) {
                    info[0].className += ' active';
                } else {
                    info[0].className = 'info';
                }
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: ul tag is menu, li tag is button, div tag is hidden block. By click to li tag active class will be installed. Click again div block hidden